# How to upload expo app to play store using eas?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to submit my first build to playstore manually, but now that Google manages the signing key by itself, On bundle upload I am getting the error saying signing key doesn't match, I guess this is because expo creates its on keys and google does its own so they are not matching now. I may be wrong in understanding the scenario, Can anyone please help me the way ahead? Thanks